# What dataccess technology is best suited for CQRS query Webservices?

Tags: c#, cqrs

What tools are people using for querying their Read database and populating DTO's?

We currently have our Read model in a Sql2008 database and perform all our queries through a WCF service, We're using Fluent NHibernate to populate the data contracts using auto-mapping, but maybe this is just overkill?

Our requirements are really this...

1. No Sql code in the Webservice
2. No mapping code in the Webservice, we ideally want to map by conventions, the Read database fields have the same names as our Data contract properties. We don't want to write and maintain mapping code by hand.
3. Minimal resource usage on the webserver.

Comment: The requirements sound like someone wrote them without being bothered by practical considerations suchas "the reality". Fire him, rewrite requirements to be sane.

Comment: TomTom : Why do you say that? With Dynamic objects, Linq, ORMs, Code generation tools, etc how is this not practical?

Comment: You realize that the speed will supper like mad? I was once in a project where the architect was fired (and had top ay damages) for a stupidity like that. You slow down database acces by 150%+ for smaller amounts of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used WCF Data Services with a lot of success on the read side. I have written a blog post about it. Check it out at http://blog.fossmo.net/post/WCF-Data-Services-A-perfect-fit-for-our-CQRS-implementation.aspx

Comment: It's a nice solution, and we're testing an implementation at present. EntityFramework might present a performance issue though

Comment: It depends on how you do the query tables and the view models. I have a one-to-one relationship between the view models and the query tables. It shouldn't affect performance.

Answer (score 3):

IMHO Overkill.

I'm using just a flat file system with JSON/ProtoBuf serialization. Web services are dead simple and schema can be anything. The stack easily moves to the cloud (using Azure Storage Blobs) for almost-infinite scalability as needed.

Details: http://abdullin.com/journal/2011/1/19/scalable-and-simple-cqrs-views-in-the-cloud.html

Comment: This is interesting. I agree with the ideas, but in our case we are integrating with a legacy ERP system, and forced to have our read models in a Sql 2008 database. So all we really need is a lightweight method of getting those views to the client from the database. Some simple queries are also required, so being able to use Linq is also a real bonus.

Answer (score 0):

I used ADO.NET core with stored procedures in the database.
Then using a tool I've written, all of the data access code is generated using the result of each stored procedure as the structure of Dtos.

The tool with source code is available on my blog
[Data Access Layer CodeGen](http://www.matlus.com/data-access-layer-codegen/)

Now since you're simply returning the data via a WCF service, then there is no need to go from
DataReader, to Dto and then serialize the DTO. In other words, you're iterating over your resultset 3 times in the process of sending the data out. So if you want to reduce the resource utilization on your server and get better performance then you can use the "DataReader-Wrapper" classes that the tool generates (along with the Data access code).

The DataReader wrapper classes are like strongly typed DataReaders. I have another post where I talk about these and their benefits
[DataReader Wrappers - TypeSafe](http://www.matlus.com/datareader-wrappers-typesafe/)

Of course, you could modify the tool (since you have the source code as well) to generate all of your code including the WCF service. So all you really have to do is write a stored procedure and you're done. All of the DataAccess code (using ADO.NET Core - so it's lightweight and super fast), business layer code and WCF code is really just "busy work" if you get what I mean.

**EDIT**
Reason for using stored procedures

1. A stored procedure can returns
   multiple result sets in one call.
2. A stored procedure can accept
   parameters.
3. A stored procedure can
   have control flow statements and can
   call other stored procedures (so you
   get procedure re-use kind of like
   refectoring a method such that you
   can call it from multiple other
   methods).
4. It is far easier to optimize a stored procedure since the tools work really well with them

Comment: Great, this is exactly what I'm looking for, I'll take a look. Is there any reason why you prefer Stored procedures over database views?

Comment: @Andronicus, I've edited my answer to include the reasons for using stored procedure. You could easily modify the tool to work off of view, tables and stored procedures. Another reason the tool uses SPs as the basis is that I use the same tool for the "other side" as well. Meaning Create, Update, Delete and there we use only stored procedures.